# Disable Eclipse Rename Context Menu

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I am working on an RCP application and I want to disable the Rename context menu under File menu. I tried a few approaches but unfortunately none of them worked for me. Following is what I have tried so far.

**Using activities**

```
 <extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.activities">
  <activity
        id="disableRenameContextMenu"
        name="Disable Rename Context Menu">
        <enabledWhen>
           <not>
              <test
                 property="com.session.ui.IsSessionActive">
              </test>
           </not>
     </enabledWhen>
  </activity>
  <activityPatternBinding
        activityId="disableRenameContextMenu"
        pattern="org.eclipse.ui.edit.rename">
  </activityPatternBinding>
```

**Using Perspective Extensions**

```
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.perspectiveExtensions">
  <perspectiveExtension
        targetID="com.perspectives.MyPerspective">
     <hiddenMenuItem
           id="org.eclipse.ui.edit.rename">
     </hiddenMenuItem>
  </perspectiveExtension>
```

**Using Command Handler**

```
<extension
   point="org.eclipse.ui.handlers">
 <handler
    class=""
    commandId="org.eclipse.ui.edit.rename">
 <enabledWhen>
    <not>
        <test
            property="com.session.ui.IsSessionActive">
        </test>
     </not>
 </enabledWhen>
```

Is there any way I can disable the Rename context menu? Am I doing anything wrong in the above approaches. any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The perspective extension should work but the id in the `hiddenMenuItem` is the menu id which is **not** the same as the command id the menu uses.

For Rename the menu id is 'rename':

```xml
<hiddenMenuItem
   id="rename">
</hiddenMenuItem>
```

Menu ids for core menu items are defined in `org.eclipse.ui.actions.ActionFactory`

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked. Is it possible to combine this approach with test Property like the others?